# How to trigger a local application from a SQL server or web server

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb6

We have created a ASP.NET website to give ticket-based support to our customers. Together with our software, we have given a separate VB6 application where customers can send queries to us, and they can see replies, if any. This application loads the ASP.NET page inside a Web Browser control. When customers send queries, it will be added to our database; and we send replies to their questions. So ultimately we will be putting replies in a "reply" column of the table.

I want to show replies to customers as soon as we add them. We have set a timer in our support application which checks whether a reply is present in the database. If so, then we show it. We need to check every 5 minutes that any replies are present in the database. So I think it is what is responsible for more traffic and load on my web server and SQL Server.

Is there any mechanism by which we can trigger the support application which loads the ASP page from the web server? whenever we add a reply to a particular customer, it should be shown to that customer. How this can be done? Are there any better ideas?

Comment: I take it you mean "Is there any mechanism *other than a timer* by which we can trigger the support application? If so, then no - well, not by the application as a simple HTTP client. Also, why don't you look at your webserver logs, rather than by guessing that the application is causing your problem. It could be something else causing the issue. A 5-minute refresh doesn't sound particularly onerous.

Comment: How many users are you supporting at one time here?  We have a low-end chat server handling 300+ requests PER SECOND (as opposed to every 5 minutes) and they're only running around 10% of CPU usage and not sluggish at all.  So... the issue could be your queries.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw  Right now I am not experiencing any large CPU usage or load due to this. But I am interested to know is there any better ideas?

Comment: Well, you could keep the connection between the client and webserver open, and doing the polling of the database on the webserver, returning data to the client only if something has changed. But I don't recommend this approach, since you will be taking up lots of webserver resources keeping those connections alive. Polling seems fine.

Comment: By the way, this is the kind of question that gets closed. Best post questions which are clearly defined problems with some actual code at the heart of them.

Comment: You could look in to sockets.  With this approach, you would create a connection to the server from VB6 using sockets.  The socket could stay idle on the VB6 side.  When there is a new message on the server, the server's socket could pass a message to the VB6 socket indicating a new message.  The VB6 app would then load the message the same way you are doing it now.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw How do asp chat applications run? How do they listen & manage the load on server easily?

Comment: No idea. I guess that they would use Javascript and XmlHttp connections.